# Replace the same character in string with an array, but on every occurence use next entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

Replace character with an array to get the desired result, but on every occurence use the next array entry.
Do you have any ideas on how to get this?

```
var str = 'a ? c ? e ?';
var arr = ['b', 'd', 'f'];
var result_str = 'a b c d e f'; //desired outcome

//I was thinking about something like
result_str = 'a ? c ? e ?'.split('?').join(['b', 'd', 'f']);
//of course it just joins the array before replaceing, so the result is
result_str = "a b,d,f c b,d,f e b,d,f"
```

Comment: Please search before asking questions. This has been asked several times already.

Answer (score 5):

You could replace the `?` with a function which takes an item of the array.

```js
var string = 'a ? c ? e ?',
    array = ['b', 'd', 'f'],
    result = string.replace(/\?/g, (i => _ => array[i++])(0));

console.log(result);
```

With shift as callback

```js
var string = 'a ? c ? e ?',
    array = ['b', 'd', 'f'],
    fn = Array.prototype.shift.bind(array),
    result = string.replace(/\?/g, fn);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It would not hurt to quickly search for duplicates when it is that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with `?` delimiter and then then use filter to remove empty string. Then use `map` to return an array of character and inside its call back use the index to retrieve element from the second array. Then use `join` to create the string

```js
var str = 'a ? c ? e ?';
var arr = ['b', 'd', 'f'];
let newStr = str.split('?')
  .filter(item => item !== "")
  .map((item, index) => item + arr[index])
  .join(' ');

console.log(newStr)
```